# Helpers not working with a modular Sinatra app

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, view-helpers

I'm having some trouble getting [helpers](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Helpers) to work with a modular Sinatra app. I have a master controller and a bunch of others inheriting from it. So `/` maps to `Root`, `/auth` maps to `Auth`, etc.

Main module:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
# Lots of other requires

# Helper
module Utils
  def test
    puts "Test helper"
    return 'test'
  end
end

# Main app
class Application < Sinatra::Base    
  helpers Utils

  # Lots of config
end
```

"Controllers" inherit `Application`, like:

```
class Root < Application

  get '/' do
    puts Utils # Exists
    puts Utils.test # Breaks

    # view() Defined directly in `Application`, runs slim
    view :index
  end

end
```

This results in:

> NoMethodError at /
>
> private method `test' called for Utils:Module

A bit stumped. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a helpers module makes all the methods in it directly available to the code in the routes, without needing to prefix it with the module name.

You can just do this:

```
get '/' do
  puts test

  # view() Defined directly in `Application`, runs slim
  view :index
end
```

The reason you are getting `` private method `test' called for Utils:Module `` rather than `` undefined method `test' for Utils:Module `` is because there already is a [`test` method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-test) in Kernel, which is therefore available as a private method on all classes.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the opposite of this (for namespacing concerns), that is, to define a module such that its helper methods can be called with the module name and still have access to the request context and Sinatra's other helpers (e.g. `session`)? In OP's example, to be able to call `Utils.test` from a route, instead of plain `test()`?

Comment: @ArmanH I saw your question and bounty about this. I don’t think there’s a clean way to do what you want. By using the name with the module the method is being run in a different context, but you need it to be in the same context to get the other helpers. (Of course, this being Ruby there may be some hacky way to get it to work).

Answer (score 1):

Well, looks like the answer is pretty simple.

When including a module via `helpers()`, its methods become available simply as `method_name()` and not `ModuleName.method_name()`.

So in this case, both in `Root` and the slim template, all I need to do is call `test()`